# XNA How can I get the color behind a sprite

Tags: colors, xna, 2d, collision, terrain

I am currently working on a 2D project that generates random black terrain over a loaded background. I have a sprite that is loaded and controlled and am trying to find out what the best method for identifying the color behind the sprite to code some color based collision. I have tried a bunch of tutorials on perpixel and color but they all seem dependant on a collision map being used or bounding boxes between two preloaded images IE: sprite and colliding object.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

Querying textures is a relatively expensive operation; I would strongly recommend that you avoid doing so in real time.  Since you're generating your terrain information procedurally at runtime, why not just store it in an array and reference that?

If you need to composite textures or perform other rendering operations in order to create your terrain data, you can copy the resulting render target's data into an array in system memory using the following code:

```
var data = new Color[width * height];
texture.GetData(data);
```

Just try to avoid doing it any more often than is necessary.

Comment: Thanks I guess we need to work something else out collision wise then it seams the consensus is perpix will eat the game alive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right direction would be away from pixel-perfect collisions. Most people assume it's necessary, but the fact is, 99% of games don't use pixel-perfect collisions because they are slow, difficult to implement properly, and overkill for most practical games. Most games use [AABBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-aligned_bounding_box), circles, or spheres. They are simple to detect collisions between, and are "good enough" for most games. The only game I can name that uses pixel-perfect collisions is the original Worms.

This video also does a good job of covering collision detection: http://pyvideo.org/video/615/introduction-to-game-development  (Collision Detection @1:13:20)

Comment: Thanks same as above seems to be the consensus.